# How to make circuit that control number of clock pulses?

Tags: digital-logic

I am trying to design my own processor and stimulate it in software.Now for that I am design a circuit that can control number of clock pulses.
For example if I input 0010 it should output two pulses.

Comment: Hint: counters can be made to count down instead of up.

Comment: ^^^ This is exactly how you should approach this. [Allaboutcircuits has a good articles about this.](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-11/synchronous-counters/) But as far as making it a synchronous or asynchronous is up to you to decide what your expectations are for your processor.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are doing this sort of thing (simulation), then in your example the most simple way is to use full adder. What you basically want to do is to build a 4bit full adder, then connect "A" inputs to the "number" you want to decrement from and "B" inputs in "0001" form (decrementing one). BUT, this way you´ll be adding 1, so you need to XOR **ALL** "B" inputs and carry in 1. This way, you´ll increment -1, so basically substract 1. Also, "A" input MUST be d-latch, and you want to wire output to "A" register, otherwise you´ll substract 1 and it will stop. This way, every clock cycle the output of adder will latch into "A" register, adder will substract (lol) and wait until next clock cycle.. I´ll provide schematics if u want, don´t have currently time :P